# Spark SQL: Catalyst is scanning undesired columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two scenarios shown below:

```
scala> val dfA = sqlContext.read.parquet("/home/mohit/ruleA")
dfA: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [aid: int, aVal: string]

scala> val dfB = sqlContext.read.parquet("/home/mohit/ruleB")
dfB: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [bid: int, bVal: string]

scala> dfA.registerTempTable("A")

scala> dfB.registerTempTable("B")
```

**1 .Left Join with Filter in WHERE**

```
sqlContext.sql("select A.aid, B.bid from A left join B on A.aid=B.bid where B.bid<2").explain

== Physical Plan ==
Project [aid#15,bid#17]
+- Filter (bid#17 < 2)
   +- BroadcastHashOuterJoin [aid#15], [bid#17], LeftOuter, None
      :- Scan ParquetRelation[aid#15,aVal#16] InputPaths: file:/home/mohit/ruleA
      +- Scan ParquetRelation[bid#17,bVal#18] InputPaths: file:/home/mohit/ruleB
```

**2. Left Join with Filter in ON**

```
sqlContext.sql("select A.aid, B.bid from A left join B on A.aid=B.bid and B.bid<2").explain

== Physical Plan ==
Project [aid#15,bid#17]
+- BroadcastHashOuterJoin [aid#15], [bid#17], LeftOuter, None
   :- Scan ParquetRelation[aid#15] InputPaths: file:/home/mohit/ruleA
   +- Filter (bid#17 < 2)
      +- Scan ParquetRelation[bid#17] InputPaths: file:/home/mohit/ruleB, PushedFilters: [LessThan(bid,2)]
```

**Question**

In either cases, `Catalyst` had information that from table B, only `B.bid` (bid#17) is required. Why did entire table scan was required in `WHERE` case. The `projection` columns for table B are implicit and deterministic.

Note: This is a watered-down example from a production issue.  Spark version - 1.6.2.

Comment: It looks like a bug - if nobody will help you here, then posting on Spark Developer group will be a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised this on Spark at [JIRA-18642](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18642). It is a genuine bug in Spark 1.6.